# IntegrityError: null value in column "categories_id" of relation "polls_products" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do CRUD with foreign keys using serializers,the issue is that I am unable to insert the data that I want to display with the below error coming :

"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "categories_id" of relation "polls_products" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (42, aw, 12, 4, good, 9, null, 3, 3, 1, t)."

I in fact made sure to add every data as shown in the images below
[image]
[image]
despite having insert every data the error is coming

below is the models and serializer

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories = models.ForeignKey(SUBCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_details = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
class POLLSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = "__all__"

class pollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
def insert(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('POST',id)
        data['categories'] = request.POST.get('categories')
        data['sub_categories'] = request.POST.get('sub_categories')
        data['color'] = request.POST.get('color')
        data['size'] = request.POST.get('size')
        data['title'] = request.POST.get('title')
        data['price'] = request.POST.get('price')
        data['sku_number'] = request.POST.get('sku_number')
        data['product_details'] = request.POST.get('product_details')
        data['quantity'] = request.POST.get('quantity')

        form = pollSerializer(data=data)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form after valid:',form)
            print("error of form:",form.errors)
            form.save()
            
            messages.success(request, "Record Updated Successfully...!:)")
            return redirect("polls:show")
        else:
            print('form not valid')
            print(form.errors)
    if request.method == "GET":
        print('POST',id)
        category_dict = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
        category = CategoriesSerializer(category_dict, many=True)
        sub_category_dict = SUBCategories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
        sub_category = SUBCategoriesSerializer(sub_category_dict,many=True)
        color_dict = Colors.objects.filter(isactive=True)
        color = ColorsSerializer(color_dict,many=True)
        size_dict = Size.objects.filter(isactive=True)
        size = SizeSerializer(size_dict,many=True)
        hm = {"context": category.data,"sub_context":sub_category.data,"color_context":color.data,"size_context":size.data}
        return render(request, "polls/product_insert.html", hm)
```

where am I going wrong in the code?

Comment: Did you run migrations/migrate?

Comment: I ran both but the compiler mentioned that there are no changes to apply.

nonetheless,the result is the same

Comment: did you try to delete your migrations?

Comment: do you mean deleteing everything in migrations folder except  __init__? I tried that as well but then I tried to do makemigrations,it doesnt happen

Comment: Ok try  add `null=True` to your Products model `categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

Comment: hi mohamed,now the data is getting inserted by,the 'categories' column is showing None,is there a way where the name of the categories is there instead of null?

Comment: Try to comment or remove this line from your `pollSerializer` this `categories = serializers.StringRelatedField()`

Comment: it worked but the thing is that I want the name of the categories in the categories colmun which is why I had placed the StringRelatedField.is there any other way to put the name of the category into the categories column?

Comment: You can't use `StringRelatedField ` in POST request because it is read-only.

Comment: ok thanks for the help,mohamed,is  there any idea you could give to insert the category name into the table?